# Samsung Kies correct version

Tags: samsung-kies

I need to find the right Kies version for Samsung S4 mini but the info provided by samsung is not clear:

Please check your mobile phone model before downloading:

**Kies**
Supported model : Feature phone, Smart Phone/Tablet before Galaxy Note III (including Galaxy S4, Note II, etc)

**Kies3**
Supported model : Smart Phone/Tablet from Galaxy Note III (Android OS 4.3 or over)

I suspect that it has to do with android version but it is not very clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Android version are you on? Check `System Settings > About phone > Android version`. Kies3 is for Android 4.3 and above. If your Android version is lower, use Kies.

Comment: it says 4.2.2. But I wonder, won't there be an update past the 4.3 for S4 mini? A samsung s3 (older smartphone) has a 4.3 version.. that's weird.

Comment: @YannisDran S4 Mini has 4.3 already, but that would depend on your network if they rolled it out already. Try to check via `Settings > About > System Updates`. If you're on a custom ROM, you usually wouldn't get an update notification. http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-s4-mini-gets-treated-to-android-4-3-1202347

Comment: It is Settings > About Device > Software update. It says that the latest updates have already been installed. So I guess I install Kies and if new version later than 4.3 comes up I will install another kies accordingly, right?

Comment: @YannisDran Correct.